# Jquery Validation Plugin - can you enable "eager" validation from the options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the Jquery Validation plugin on a project.

By default, the plugin validates input when the submit button is clicked. The behavior is "lazy" in order to be unobtrusive to the user. If an error is found, the validation then becomes "eager" and validates input as the user corrects the offending entries.

Is there any way to override the initial "lazy" behavior through an option? I can't find any solution in the documentation.

Example:

If you look at this [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/), you will notice that the user can navigate through the form leaving empty text boxes that will fail validation when the user clicks on submit. If the user initially enters an invalid email address on the email textbox, it is not highlighted until the submit button is clicked. 
After that, the input is validated on each key press and blur event. That is what I'd like to activate from the start.

I understand the design choice of the plugin creator, but I need different behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the default behavior I get is validation on the `focusout` and `keyup` events, which I see in the plugin code as defaults.  I have to disable those in the plugin configuration in order to only get validation at submit.  Perhaps you should post some of your code... I don't think the situation is completely clear.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I've expanded my question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't get the same behavior as you get from that demo.  Errors are displayed for me as I navigate through the form.  Possibly you should include your browser and version in the question and try some other ones.

Comment: Hmm, though I do see that if I leave fields blank they don't validate until submit.  It's if I enter something invalid (including an invalid email), or blank it out after an error is displayed, that it works.

Comment: I think you can force the behavior you want by adding onfocusout: function() { $(this).valid() } to your validate() setup call.

Comment: Except with the semicolon where it should be.  Like $('#myform').validate({ onfocusout: { $($this).valid(); } };

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick:

$('#myform').validate({ onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); } };

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to chaos for guidance on this question:

To enable eager validation on the jquery validation plugin, add the following option to the validate function:

```
 $('#myform').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        $(element).valid();
    }
});
```

Comment: don't know why, this doesn't work for my side. whatever I defined in the options of validate({...}), it doesn't seem to be triggered.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Anyone know what @Elaine and I are missing?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to Robert's answer that you can do this in the default settings by using [`setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults) so it doesn't rely on tapping into the actual instance of the validate method (which is not typically exposed with unobtrusive validation).

Just override the [`onfocusout`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout) property with a function that always evaluates the blurred element by calling the [`valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method:

```js
// enable eager evaluation
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    }
})
```

**Demo With Eager Evaluation**:
<sup>(Will show required after tab out)</sup>

```js
// enable eager evaluation
$.validator.setDefaults({
  onfocusout: function (element) {
    $(element).valid();
  }
});

$("form").validate();
```

```css
input.error {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form >
  <input type="text" name="Name" required /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" required /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Normal Demo**
<sup>(Won't show required until submit)</sup>

```js
$("form").validate();
```

```css
input.error {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form >
  <input type="text" name="Name" required /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" required /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the onfocusout was also not working.  I have tried to add it via setDefaults like suggested by KyleMit and via $('#myform').validate.

The solution that I finally have used is to add an extra event on keyup, blur and change for the different fields of my form.  I have used a class instead of an id to keep the logic generic.

```
$('body').on('keyup blur change', '.tovalidate input, .tovalidate select, .tovalidate textarea', function () { 
        $('.tovalidate').validate().checkForm(); 
});
```