# ASP.NET MVC 3 validation on blur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

How do I call the validation when the textbox looses focus? Eg.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
}

public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also, How can I check if the name exist already by calling an action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remote validation is a new feature of MVC 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: thats exactly what the linked sample does

Comment: `Required` in the sample doesn't work on blur, everything else does. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this behavior: [Jquery Validation Plugin - can you enable "eager" validation from the options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934575/jquery-validation-plugin-can-you-enable-eager-validation-from-the-options)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable eager evaluation by using [`setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults) to override the [`onfocusout`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout) property with a function that always evaluates the blurred element by calling the [`valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method.

```js
// enable eager evaluation
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    }
})
```

**Demo With Eager Evaluation**:
<sup>(Will show required after tab out)</sup>

```js
// enable eager evaluation
$.validator.setDefaults({
  onfocusout: function (element) {
    $(element).valid();
  }
});

$("form").validate();
```

```css
input.error {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form >
  <input type="text" name="Name" required /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" required /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Normal Demo**
<sup>(Won't show required until submit)</sup>

```js
$("form").validate();
```

```css
input.error {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form >
  <input type="text" name="Name" required /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" required /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```