# change default behavior of unobtrusive jquery validation to validate on onkeyup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using micrososofts unobtrusive jquery validation with MVC4 / razor and the default behavior appears to be to first validate on click of submit, and then after that validate onkeyup.

I'd like to change it so it starts validating onblur, and then after the first submit continues to validate on keyup as normal.

Is there a way I can change it to start validating on blur for all forms?

Comment: You've just described the default behavior of jQuery Validate plugin.  Enter less than five characters in the first field and click into the next field in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UmW3H/

Comment: @Sparky I don't think the default behavior is the same in [Microsoft's Unobtrusive Validation](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/)

Comment: It should be.  `unobtrusive` totally depends on jQuery Validate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Validation Plugin - can you enable "eager" validation from the options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934575/jquery-validation-plugin-can-you-enable-eager-validation-from-the-options)

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behaviour when using jquery validate directly or via Microsoft unobtrusive validation.  If you enter a non valid entry into a field, that field will be validated on blur even before the field is submitted.  If you focus and then blur a field without entering anything this field will only be validated on submitting the form.

From the documentation page section ["A few things to look for when playing around with the demo"](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#A_few_things_to_look_for_when_playing_around_with_the_demo)

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy [but] if
>   the user enters something in a non-marked field, and tabs/clicks away
>   from it (blur the field), it is validated

I have forked the fiddle in the comment to demonstrate this using the unobtrusive plugin and some rendered html.  http://jsfiddle.net/8wkS2/

"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code." so here is the rendered markup produced by the server

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" 
data-val="true" 
data-val-required="This field is required"
data-val-length="The field LastName must be a string with a minimum length of 5." 
data-val-length-min="5" />
```