# MVC Model validation on lose focus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to change **when** client side validation happens when using MVC data annotations?  Currently, all validation seems to occure on `keyup`, but I need it to occure `onchange` or `losefocus`.

`ViewModel`:

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

`cshtml`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.FirstName) }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div class="field">
    <input data-val="true" 
           data-val-required="First Name is Required" 
           id="FirstName" 
           name="FirstName" 
           placeholder="First Name" 
           type="text" 
           value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

This works as it should, but when I type into input, validation occurs as I type.  How can I make validation occure after I've clicked or tabbed off the input?

**Versions**

- .NET 4.6.1
- Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc 5.2.3
- Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 3.2.3

Comment: Which version are you using exactly? Microsoft's unobtrusive validation [works on `blur`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16078767/11683) to begin with.

Comment: Do you mean .NET version?  It is .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: No, the MVC version - that will have to be 5 then. Try updating your nuget packages for MVC and unobtrisive validation.

Comment: @GSerg I updated the post with the versions.  Visual Studio is reporting these versions as the latest stable.

Comment: Does it happen in a different browser?

Comment: Yes, tested in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use Javascript to get the desired behavior.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: false
})
```

All validation now happens on `blur`